# Send id with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Today I have a problem sending id with ajax and jquery ,I have a foreach in the view of laravel like this ,

```
<div class="ident" id="auctionIdentifier-{{$i}}" auction="{{$auction->id}}"></div>
```

this in the elements recieve correctly the id of auctions but when I try to doing a click I only send the first id.

I don't know when I doing a click in the next bid , I don't send the id corresponding.
    id}}">

```
    $(".inscription").click(function(){
        console.log($(".ident").attr('auction'));
        $.ajax({
                url:'../bid/inscription',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
                success:  function (response) {
                    console.log("ok");
                },              
        });
    });
```

Comment: what happens when you click second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this helps:

```
 $(".ident").click(function(){

        var id = $(this).attr('auction');

        $.ajax({
                url:'../bid/inscription',
                dataType:'json',
                type:'get',
                cache:true,
                data: {
                  id: id
                },
                success:  function (response) {
                    console.log("ok");
                },              
        });
 });
```

Basically you need to get the currently clicked element auction attribute. Also you might want to add `data-` in front of it like so: `data-auction="VALUE"`. This way you can get it with `$(el).data('auction')`.

Comment: I need this , is the same but I only change (this) , I supose because get the actual element with this option. Thanks !